# Modifying more than one tagss value in xml using xpath in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Can we change the value of more than one tags in `xml` using `xpath`.

Comment: give some example or sample xml please?

Comment: XPath can only select, not modify. You need to select items using XPath, then use some other C# code to modify them.

Comment: Hi i am able to do this by Xpathnavigator. Thanks a lot.XpathNavigator selcts as well as modifies the element and stores modified in temporary buffer.